# Do before_filter :except work across subclass controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

I want to declare some methods from a different controller in `ApplicationController`'s filter like below:

In `ApplicationContoller`

`before_filter :authorize, :except => [:index, :show, :different_controller_method]`

where `:different_controller_method` is defined in `UserController`. Can we do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally this should work. Make sure you are using symbols, as @jdl is saying.

Most of the times we use a different approach though. In your `ApplicationController` you write

```
before_filter :authorize
```

So that by definition all access is authorized. In your `UsersController` you can then add an exception:

```
skip_before_filter :authorize, :only => [:index, :show, :different_controller_method]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I did the same. but its not working for me. Your and mine code are exactly same as I posted in the form see above and let me know where I'm doing mistake.

Comment: What do you mean with: it is not working? Are you receiving an error? Does it not work for all the methods? Are the methods spelled correctly? Please describe what happens in more detail. Otherwise it is very hard to be of any help.

Comment: No except scope working for only application methods only,and I need to make it work for other controller's method as well. Was I make it my question clear to you ?

Comment: For test: move that statement to the correct controller: does it work there? My hunch is that it won't.

Answer (score 1):

But do you want to keep it that way? Imagine someone else is reading through your UserController class definition. She would check whether there are any filters on UserController#differnt_controller_method usually by looking in the same file you have defined UserController class. Not finding any filters there she would assume differnt_controller_method does not have any filters.

It is best to keep related things together otherwise maintaining the application becomes hard because adding a feature or fixing a bug would require many files to be changed. I highly recommend that you watch [this talk](http://confreaks.net/videos/240-goruco2009-solid-object-oriented-design) by Sandi Metz given at GoRuCo 2009.

Comment: Thanks Ardsrk! But I just want to how we can do it?

Comment: Ok. But I wanted to tell you the right way of doing it. Declaring filters related to a controller method in the same controller class is a Rails convention.

Answer (score 1):

In cleaning up the grammar of your question, I noticed that you did not use a symbol to describe your 'different' method.

`before_filter :authorize, :except => [:index, :show, :different_controller_method]`

and not

`before_filter :authorize, :except => [:index, :show, different_controller_method]`

Notice the colon.

Comment: if you use without column ,it will give you error :
undefined local variable or method `different_controller_method'.

and I am using :except[:different_controller_method]

Answer (score 0):

> Can we do this ?

Yes, you can.

Comment: As you described it (:except in ApplicationController should work fine)